# Get max number with lowest number of steps

Tags: graph-theory, sorting

I have a csv with Rows of data. Each row consists of an `amount_of_apples` and a number of `steps`. The amount_of_apples are the total number of apples in a room and the steps is the distance in steps to the room.

```
amount_of_apples, steps
20, 8
44, 3
19, 1
12, 2
2,  8
88, 14
51, 3
59, 1
31, 8
30, 9
```

I would like to know what is the max number of apples I can collect if I can only travel max_steps a day e.g 100.

My current solution involves sorting the rooms by weight and then visiting each room according to weight.

`weight := numberOfApples / steps`

So I’d go to the room with 59 apples that’s 1 step away first and then the room with 51 apples that’s 3 steps away next. I’d then visit the next room in the list with a number of step smaller than my remaining steps and continue until I run out of rooms or steps.

current solution:

```
// sort rooms by weight ratio of apples to steps
sort.SliceStable(rooms, func(i, j int) bool {
        currRatio := rooms[i].numberOfApples/ rooms[i].steps
        nextRatio := rooms[j].numberOfApples / rooms[i].steps
        return currRatio > nextRatio
    })

var results []Room
    var index int
    var count float64
    var steps int
    for steps < maxSteps {
     step += rooms[index].steps
        if steps > maxSteps {
            break
        }
        results = append(results, rooms[index])
        count += rooms[index].numberOfApples
        index += 1
    }

log.Printf("The max number of apples that can be collected in %vsteps is %v", maxSteps, count)
```

However, I do not think this is the correct solution.

Comment: I _think_ this is a variant of the knapsack problem. If so, you're in trouble. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Comment: Looks like you’re right. I’ll check it out. Thanks!

Comment: "distance in steps to the room": from where?  After you travel to the first room, don't the distances change?

Comment: Assuming the answer to RobPratt's question is no (meaning that your description is misleading), your algorithm is good, but there are some cases where it is suboptimal. For example suppose you have 4 steps left and have two rooms 2 steps away with 8 apples each, and one room 3 steps away with 15 apples. Per your algorithm you would go to the 15 apple room and stop, wasting the last step. But forgoing this option to pick up the two 8 apple rooms is superior. This can be corrected by recognizing the actual cost of the 15 apple room at this point is 4 steps, not the advertised 3.